# How to properly use `\fontfamily` with `fontspec` and `lualatex`

Tags: luatex, fontspec

For my thesis I'm being asked to use a specific latex template.

This template includes several invocations of the style:

```
\fontfamily{cmss}\fontseries{m}\fontsize{22}{26}\selectfont
```

and

```
\fontfamily{fvs}\fontseries{m}\fontsize{8}{12}\selectfont
```

To change the fonts throughout title pages etc..

I am using lualatex, and I'm trying to get these commands to work with `fontspec`.

From searches on this site and elsehwere it seems like I should be able to use 'New Computer Modern' as a replacement font family but I cannot get that to work. How do I actually change the font family?

Comment: well it depends what your template is doing. Without other font setup interfering the first can be replaced by \sffamily, the second is a bera font and can be replaced by dejavu. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/443235/2388

Comment: The template has code for specific title and header pages in which lines like those in my post are interspersed. 

I don't think I want to use `\setmainfont` etc.. because I need *both* these fonts in different sections of the document. Can I not just replace the `fontfamily` with something else? The `fontspec` manual seems to say that it's a valid command.

Comment: The answer will depend on what the template code is actually doing. To (re)define legacy font families with system/Unicode fonts, use the `NFSSFamily=` option e.g., `\usepackage{fontspec}\newfontfamily{\myfont}{TeX Gyre Pagella}[NFSSFamily=cmss]`. Note that `fontspec` makes modern OpenType/TrueType fonts available for use by (xe/lua)latex.

Comment: Unrelated: It is not clear why changing a template is required: if you are required to use a template, then changing it departs from some standard. (e.g., will any archival/publication step work with the modified template?)

Comment: > Unrelated: It is not clear why changing a template is required: if you are required to use a template

I'm required to have the *result* of the template as the title page of my thesis but it's not actually required to use that specific template since you can also use Word or other typesetting systems for your thesis.

Comment: I'm going to put together an MWE pulled from the actual template. Hopefully it'll make things more concrete.