# libertine + beramono + LuaLaTeX incompatible

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, libertine, beramono

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{beramono}

\begin{document}
This is some regular text

\texttt{This is some monospace text}
\end{document}
```

If I compile this with `pdflatex` then the result is as expected: the regular text is in the Libertine font, and the monospace text is in the Bera Mono font.

If I compile this with `lualatex` then the monospace text is in the default (Computer Modern?) font. I expected it to be the same as pdflatex's output.

[image]

I have tried passing `[mono=false]` option to the libertine package, but it makes no difference.

How do I fix this?

Comment: the libertine package detects luatex and then loads fontspec which changes the encoding from T1 to TU (the encoding recommended for unicode engines). beramono doesn't support this encoding. Remove the fontenc line, and use `\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}` to setup the mono font, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/443235/2388

Answer (score 3):

If you are happy to switch to `lualatex` then you probably should use `fontspec` explicitly.  I've installed Bitstream Vera and Libertine on my Mac, and this is how I would use them to get the combination the OP wants:

```
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage{libertine}
% \usepackage{beramono}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont{Bitstream Vera Sans}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\setmonofont{Bitstream Vera Sans Mono}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

\begin{document}
This is some regular text.  \textsf{Sans text}.

\texttt{This is some monospace text}
\end{document}
```

The names I have used for the fonts are the names that appear in FontBook.app after I have installed them.  The `Scale` parameter helps to make the families look consistent.

Compiling the example above with `lualatex` produces this:

[image]